# Add one box on top of another in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add 6 boxes, 2 boxes in a row.(3 rows and 2 columns)
Below code will show 2 boxes in a column and row.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel"> <br> <!--  style="background:#e8e8e8"-->
        <div class="panelTitle"><a href="link1.html">Story</a></div><br>
        <p>
        Text.</p>
        <br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3  col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="panel"><br> 
        <div class="panelTitle"><a href="Lead.html">Lead</a></div><br>
            <h1>Text</h1>               
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel{
 position:absolute;
<!--  left:250px; -->
  float:right;
height:350px;
width:380px;
border:2px solid lavender;
background-color: #e8e8e8;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
margin:20px;
}


.panelTitle{
text-align:center;
color:red;
}
```

when I copy and paste this code to get 2 more boxes, it does not show the below the 1st 2 boxes. it gets overlapped.

It should be like

[[image: Desired output[1]]

What am I missing here?

Comment: _“What am I missing here?”_ – how absolute positioning works, presumably.

Comment: Got that. Thanks CBroe.

Comment: `.panel` is also used by Bootstrap, you might not want to override that.

Answer (score 0):

add another "div class="row"".  Each row should contain your 2 boxes. Like this:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel"> <br> <!--  style="background:#e8e8e8"-->
        <div class="panelTitle"><a href="link1.html">Story</a></div><br>
        <p>
        Text.</p>
        <br>
        </div>

        <div class="panelTitle"><a href="link1.html">Story</a></div><br>
        <p>
        Text.</p>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel"> <br> <!--  style="background:#e8e8e8"-->
        <div class="panelTitle"><a href="link1.html">Story</a></div><br>
        <p>
        Text.</p>
        <br>
        </div>

        <div class="panelTitle"><a href="link1.html">Story</a></div><br>
        <p>
        Text.</p>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel"> <br> <!--  style="background:#e8e8e8"-->
        <div class="panelTitle"><a href="link1.html">Story</a></div><br>
        <p>
        Text.</p>
        <br>
        </div>

        <div class="panelTitle"><a href="link1.html">Story</a></div><br>
        <p>
        Text.</p>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Andre.  position:absolute; should be removed from CSS.

Comment: that's correct yes, alongside with more rows for better syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer,
 **position:absolute;** should be removed from the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

are your rows in a container?

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

and if yes, I think the absolute positioning on "panel" prevent the float.

You can eventually set the absolute positioning on the parent.

```
#containerParent{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
}
```

But with bootstrap, you shouldn't need to use your own float for the layout,
using a row,

with col-md-6 and using display: block; on your panel element should be enought to get what you want.

------row------

--col1--col2--

--col3--col4--

------row------

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

**HTML**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <!--     Fonts     -->
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Grand+Hotel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>


<div class="services">
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="box-sevices">
            <p>
            ambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="box-sevices">

            <p>
            ambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<br/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="box-sevices">
            <p>
            ambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="box-sevices">

            <p>
            ambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<br/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="box-sevices">
            <p>
            ambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="box-sevices">
            <p>
            ambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>  
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
    body{
        font-family: Segoe UI ;
    }
    .main_header {
        background: rgb(37, 35, 35) none repeat scroll 0 0;
        padding:10px 0;
    }
    .btn.btn-default.btn_more {
        background: rgb(127, 183, 59) none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border: medium none;
        border-radius: 6px;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 4px 25px;
        margin-right:20px;
    }
    .btn.btn-default.btn_info {
        background: rgb(127, 183, 59) none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border: medium none;
        border-radius: 6px;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 4px 10px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .fa_right_padding {
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 4px;
    }
    .panel_bar {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border: medium none;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.menu_bar_top {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.menu_bar_top a {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        font-size: 16px;
        padding:12px 15px;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.menu_bar_top a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: rgb(127, 183, 59);
        border-radius:6px;

    }
    a:focus {
        outline: medium none;
        outline-offset: 0;
    }

.left.carousel-control.form_btn {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    opacity:1;
}
.right.carousel-control.form_btn {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    opacity:1;
}



.head {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.head > span {
    color: rgb(82, 133, 43);
}
.phara {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 20px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-align: center;
}
.icon1 {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    vertical-align: top;
    float:left;
}
.phara1 {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    display: flex;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.bullet_point {
    padding: 20px 0 10px;
    margin-left:150px;
}
.bullet_point.right {
    padding: 0;
}
.ima_tag {
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.box-sevices {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.head2 {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
}
.box-sevices li a {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.box-sevices a:hover {
    color: rgb(127, 183, 59);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.box-sevices > ul {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.box-sevices > ul {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.services {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.trail_acess_load {
    padding: 15px 0;

}
.head1 {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.icon2 {
    margin-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    opacity:0.80;
    margin-top:-6px;
}
.phara2 {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.trail_acess{
    background: #599425;
}
.phara2 > a {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.footer {
    background: rgb(37, 35, 35) none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
.head3 {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 21px;
}
.about_us > p {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    opacity: 0.7;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    }
.about_us > span {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size:16px;
}

.about_us {
    padding: 30px 10px;
}
.about_us > ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.about_us li {
    list-style: outside none none;
}
.about_us a {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 16px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.about_us a:hover {
    color: rgb(127, 183, 59);
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity:1;
}
.read {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.read:hover{
    color:rgb(127, 183, 59) !important;
}
.phara3{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 24px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.icon3 {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.icon3.ic1 {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.icon4:hover {
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-name: popover-social;
}
@keyframes popover-social {
    0%   {opacity:0.5;}
    99%  {transform:scale(1.7); opacity:0; }
    100% {opacity:1;}
}
.navbar.navbar-default.panel_bar {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.icon4 {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.link_footer {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

.phara5 {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.main_footer {
    background: rgb(58, 56, 56) none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

@media(min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px){
    .box-sevices {
    min-height: 441px;
}
    .bullet_point {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
    .icon1_ic1.img-responsive {
    width: 90%;
}
    .navbar-header.change{
        width:24%;
    }
    .navbar-brand.logo_desing{
        padding:15px 0 ;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.menu_bar_top a {
    font-size: 14px;
}
    .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.menu_bar_top a:hover {
    font-size: 14px;
}
    .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.menu_bar_top {
    margin-top: 26px;
}
    .navbar.navbar-default.panel_bar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

}
@media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){
    .head2 {
    font-size: 19px;

}
    .box-sevices {
    min-height: 523px;
}
    .head2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
    .box-sevices li a {
    line-height: 26px;
}
    .bullet_point {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 20px 0 10px;
}
    .navbar-brand.logo_desing{
        padding:15px 0 ;
    }
    .icon1_ic1.img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
}
    .navbar-header.change {
    width: 20%;
}
    .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.menu_bar_top a {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 12px 10px;
}
    .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.menu_bar_top a:hover {
    font-size: 12px;
}
    .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.menu_bar_top {
    margin-top: 18px;
}
    .navbar.navbar-default.panel_bar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

}
@media(max-width: 768px){
    .bullet_point {
    margin-left: 0;
}
    .box-sevices {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.box-sevices {
    max-width: 320px;
    width: 100%;
}

}
@media(min-width: 768px){
    .glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right.btn_rounded {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: rgb(115, 115, 114);
    font-size: 28px;
    height: 45px;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 45px;
    top: 40%;
}
    .glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-left.btn_rounded{
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: rgb(115, 115, 114);
    font-size: 28px;
    height: 45px;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 45px;
    top: 40%;
}
}
```

Comment: Include bootstrap.css